# ASP.NET Core Template Pack -wont create project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to use Steve Sanderon's "ASP.NET Core + Angular 2 template for Visual Studio"

Basically it uses  .net core and some other stuff to set up a Visual Studio project for Angular2 development.

When I try to create a new project using the "" template, I get the error

```
The imported project "c:\program files(x86)\msbuild\microsoft\visualstudio\v14.0\dotnet\microstoft.dotnet.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declarration is correct and that the file exists on disk. C:\users\****\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\angular2application\angular2application\angular2Application.xproj"
```

I had to type this in manually, ive checked it, but cant promise there is not a typo...but you get the idea.

if you follow the first path, there is no ...\v14.0\dotnet folder

the second path is where VS wants to put projects , the path exists up to ..\visual studio 2015\projects\
but it will not create the project folder. 
If I ask VS to create a solution folder, it does create that.

I have installed the following

vs 2015 update 3

.net core 1.1 -[I did run through the initialization script found here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015)

TypeScript 2.03

Node v6.10.1

For some reason, some folders did not get installed.
Hoping someone has run into this, or has some ideas...

Comment: probably .net core 1.1 isn't compatible with vs2015, you should use vs2017

Comment: you need to use VS 2017 or VS Code if you are working with .NET Core 1.1

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I could not get this to work.

I installed vs2017 community edition

[I then followed this article to install the templates](https://jonhilton.net/2017/02/21/create-a-vs2017-angular-2-and-net-core-site-using-the-command-line/)

Note, you have to close all instances of VS for this to work correctly. I installed them once and did not get the correct results. I closed everything , tried again, and it worked like a champ.